# How to organize the architecture of javascript form generator using a templates and BEM methodology?

Tags: javascript, architecture, mustache, bem

How to organize the architecture javascript-generator forms using a template and BEM methodology?

Good day!

The essence of the problem is as follows:
It is necessary to organize the generator forms based on json file with the description of control, like:
"Order": ["input1", "input2", "cb3"],
"Input1": {
"Type": "input",
"Title": "The first INPUT"
"Path": "root.input",
"Visible": true,
"Editable": true
}
"Input2": {...}

Types available for processing controls should be easily extensible. The data in the control must be extracted from the data source (they are available in the lines, paths in the property path, described in the control). The data source must be placed in a separate module, and shall provide public methods to retrieve data from it in the ways.

Working with the DOM should occur through the jQuery library, or (preferably) i-bem. It is necessary to describe the controls and components of the page in the ideology of BEM.

As the template syntax to use syntax mustache.

Using jquery + mustache. Deliberate over whether to use the organization to require js mvc application structure.
Can you please tell how to better organize the application architecture using a template mustache? (Because before they were not encountered, just beginning to learn)
How can I apply the BEM-approach without using BEM technology stack?

PS. Sorry for my English.

Comment: What exactly do you want to know:
1. File structure
2. JS implementation of generator
3. Templates for each block
4. Something else?

Answer (score 2):

i-bem.js implementation for a block which should generate controls inside of it can look like this:

```
modules.define('form', ['i-bem__dom', 'mu', 'tmpl'], function(provide, BEMDOM, mu, tmpl) {

provide(BEMDOM.decl(this.name, {
    onSetMod: {
        js: {
            inited: function() {
                this.generate(this.params);
            }
        }
    },
    generate: function(opts) {
        var html = opts.Order.map(function(control) {
            return mu.render(tmpl, buildopts[control]); // assuming you have client-size mustache renderer in mu module and compiled templates in tmpl
        }).join('');

        BEMDOM.append(this.domElem, html);
    }
}));

});
```

So it HTML you'll get
`<form class="form i-bem" data-bem="{'form':{ HERE GOES JSON DESCRIPTION OF COMPONENTS YOU SUGGESTED }}"></form>`. When `form` will be inited, it'll iterate over `Order` array and append the result of templates rendering inside of itself.